# Ring Signatures and the new view tags for fast wallet scanning

Tags: ring-signatures, viewkey

Do the new view tags that make wallet scanning faster also make ring signatures less effective? Do all the signatures in any ring produce the same view tag, so that there will end up being 256 different pools of ring signatures?

Comment: Do you mean view _tags_ (not keys)?

Comment: Yes. View tags. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> Do the new view tags that make wallet scanning faster also make ring signatures less effective?

No. A ring signature is on the *inputs* to a transaction. View tags are attached to the *outputs* of a transaction.

> Do all the signatures in any ring produce the same view tag, so that there will end up being 256 different pools of ring signatures?

View tags are attached to transaction *outputs* and are not derived from the input signature(s), they are derived from the shared secret and output index. So no, there will not be "256 different pools of ring signatures".

Footnote: For readers unaware, [view tags](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/8061) are not yet merged, though likely will be soon.